# NodeJS Redis Session does not persist over browser redirects

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, redis, session-cookies

I am still quite new to node and am experimenting with session management using express + redis.

My current project requires the user to be redirected to an external site to authenticate. After authentication, the browser is redirected to a callback url that i've specified. I require session data to persist across the redirect.

**My implementation is as follows:**

1. User triggers POST call to nodeJS server, where I persist data to session by `req.session.foo = 'bar'` and then return an auth_url to the browser.
2. Browser redirects using `window.location.replace(auth_url);` to external site for authentication
3. After authentication, browser is redirected to `localhost:3000/mycallbackurl` which is a route defined below (pardon the poor formatting):

> router.get('/mycallback', function(req, res) {
>
> ```
>   console.log("data at callback: " + req.session.foo);
>   //do other stuff
> ```
>
> });

My problem now is that the console prints: `data at callback: undefined` at the callback route.

Is this a problem with my redis setup, or am I just missing something here?

So far i've ascertained that redis is working by incrementing a value stored in req.session on each browser refresh and printing it.

**My redis setup is as follows:**

```
var session = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({ store: new RedisStore({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 6379,
    db: 1,
    cookie: { maxAge: (24*3600*1000*30)},
}), secret: 'keyboard cat',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));
```

Thanks for reading and look forward to your replies!

Answer (score 0):

After a redirect (res.redirect), the res and req objects are recreated.  That means if you added any parameters to these objects, you need to be sure they are re-added to the req or res objects on each request.

Comment: i am using Redis to persist data to disk and then access that data after a redirect. Is my implementation incorrect? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: What I mean is that you need to reassign a value to req.session.foo for each request.  It does not matter if that value is coming from Redis or elsewhere.  I look at your code and I do not see any assignment of value to req.session.foo so it will be undefined when you reference it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply once again. In the callback route, I require the data that was previously in `req.session.foo`. How can I persist data and retrieve it after a redirect? Surely Redis can help me achieve that?